# Colorbox on IE, opens a colorbox and then immediately follows the link off the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, colorbox

I have a gallery page that lists a grid of images. On clicking one of the images, I want the colorbox to popup and allow the user to cycle through the images.

Using a simple colorbox does this on all browsers, except IE. IE still follows the link even after opening the colorbox.

The original code:

```
$('a.gallery_image').colorbox({
    transition: 'fade',
    opacity: 0.7,
    speed: 100,
    fixed: true,
    rel: 'gal_img',
    scalePhotos: true,
    maxWidth: ($(window).width() / 100) * 85,
    maxHeight: ($(window).height() / 100) * 85
});
```

I have managed to have a similar effect using the following:

```
$('a[rel="gallery_image"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('a[rel="gallery_image"]').colorbox({
        maxWidth: '90%',
        initialWidth: '200px',
        initialHeight: '200px',
        speed: 700,
        rel: 'gal_img',
        overlayClose: false
    });
$.colorbox({
    href: $(this).attr('href')
});
//return false;
});
```

However, IE still has the same issue. if I  then uncomment the return false;. IE will no longer leave the page, but the colorbox does not act as a gallery meaning users cannot scroll through the images.

I'm out of ideas as to how to stop IE from following the link, or why it even is in the first place.

Comment: Which IE version? Older version are really picky about missing comma's. (after maxHeight: ($(window).height() / 100) * 85 and overlayClose: false)

Comment: IE7 through to 10, and I had the same issue even when I was letting it decide the widths etc

Comment: Also just tried the comma (mis understood what you were pointing out first time), and unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be having an itemprop="image" on the image url. Not really sure why that caused the issue but removing it has resolved the issue. This means that the JS is back to my original:

```
$('a.gallery_image').colorbox({
    transition: 'fade',
    opacity: 0.7,
    speed: 100,
    fixed: true,
    rel: 'gal_img',
    scalePhotos: true,
    maxWidth: ($(window).width() / 100) * 85,
    maxHeight: ($(window).height() / 100) * 85
});
```